# getting error while fetching image in node js using Resemble js

Tags: node.js

I am using  [Resemble Js](https://github.com/HuddleEng/Resemble.js/) for comparing two image using Node. I am getting error " **error while reading from input stream**" fetching external url image.
code works fine when I access images locally.Thanks in advance .

```
const http = require('http-server');
const compareImages = require('resemblejs/compareImages');
const resemble = require('resemblejs');
const fs = require("mz/fs");
const request = require('request');
const FileReader = require('filereader');
const stream = require('stream');

var file = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_combatgo-640x360.jpg";
var file2 = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_combatgo-640x360.jpg";
// var file3 = "./kritika.png";
// var file4 = "./some gal.png"

async function getDiff() {
    const options = {
        output: {
            errorColor: {
                red: 255,
                green: 0,
                blue: 255
            },
            errorType: 'movement',
            transparency: 0.3,
            largeImageThreshold: 1200,
            useCrossOrigin: false,
            outputDiff: true
        },
        scaleToSameSize: true,
        ignore: ['nothing', 'less', 'antialiasing', 'colors', 'alpha'],
    };

    // request.get(file, (err, res) => {
    //     this.newFile = file;
    //     console.log("SAMPLE RECEPT",newFile);
    //     return newFile;
    // });

    var diff = resemble(file2).compareTo(file2).onComplete(
        (data) => {
            console.log("Data", data);
        }
    );

    // await fs.writeFile('./output.png', data.getBuffer());

    // The parameters can be Node Buffers
    // data is the same as usual with an additional getBuffer() function

}

getDiff();
```